# Unable to connect to SQL Anywhere 16 using Java

Tags: java, eclipse, sybase, sqlanywhere

I'm trying to connect to a Sybase Database that is installed on another machine remotely.Using Eclipse IDE. I found one article mentioning that i need to copy the sajdbc4.jar file from "SQL Anywhere 16 > Java" install location to my project in Eclipse.

I did this and also added the jar to the java class path and went to the Eclipse Build Path -> Library-> selected the jar and set the Native path to the folder located where the jar is located.

However I'm getting "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no dbjodbc16 in java.library.path " exception when i try to run the project.

I found another article that mentions i need to use jodbc4.jar instead of the sajdbc.jar

I'm really confused which is the correct jar to use and how to resolve this exception.

Comment: did you try using jodbc4.jar instead of the sajdbc.jar?

Comment: Yes i tried this as well but i get the same exception.

Comment: I tried running the same code with the sajdbc.jar on another machine and it works fine there. So it looks like there's some problem with my laptop.

Comment: It looks like if the script is run on the machine, on which SQL Anywhere 16 is installed, only sajdbc.jar is needed. However if we are connecting remotely to the database from another machine a whole set of dll including sadjbc.jar is needed and these jars need to be placed on the Windows path.  Took hell lot of time to find out this info. Hope it helps someone out.